Currently I post many ads on craigslist and do not get many leads--where else should I post advertisements?
I've been posting ads on craigslist for several years now and have noticed as of late that my leads are drying up, both for me and for my business partners.
Besides the obvious "post ads on google" answer, which trust me, I am seriously considering it, what else would you guys recommend I do to get more leads? Are there any agencies or companies that can help me get my brand name out there more as well besides google? I don't have money for TV ads, so that is not possible for me.
What would you all recommend I do in regards to advertising to get more leads? I apologize that it's such an open ended question, and I hope I am posting about this in the right place.
I run a freelance PC repair and web design business and I also post ads for several of my friends businesses as well. I have a personal website, but it still needs some work.

Try to specify better your sort of business on your post. That way, all of community will can help you as helpful as possible.

Do you really see this as about Freelancing? Might it not be better Posted somewhere concentrating on Advertising, Marketing or Promotion, for instance?

With any ads, the question is: where do potential customers look for information about services like mine? This question has different answers for every different business.
Some businesses advertise in local publications such as neighborhood newsletters, community newspapers, or on Nextdoor. Others go door to door distributing flyers. One person I knew walked business to business handing out brochures about his IT support business and built it into a good business. Others work with networking groups and chamber of commerce events to build their business. Still others build on LinkedIn posting every week and pulling people to their profile.
Google ads / Bing ads is a way to spend a lot of money. The typical recommendation from Google ad advisors is to be spending $300 or more a month just to get the word out. There can be a lot of "impressions", a lot of fake clicks, and very little in the way of sales.
We can't give you a recommendation because what works for you is dependent both on your personality / your business style, and your potential customer base.

I well and truly do appreciate the feedback...That's exactly what I'm missing these days.
